# CodeIgniter4 API Reference Guide: Where do I find the method list of a framework's core class?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I was following a tutorial and I saw this line in it:

```
$fileSampul = $this->request->getFile('sampul');
```

Now, I'm wondering if there are more variations of this `get()` method I can use. Or at the very least, I want a place to see it with an explanation of its usage since I can't find the possible list.

Comment: You know that CodeIgniter has documentation, right?

Comment: @Olivier yes I know that, but this is what I ended up looking at https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/incomingrequest.html?highlight=upload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Solution 1: Using the GitHub repository's Filter Symbols’s search bar

*CodeIgniter4 GitHub repository's [`IncomingRequest`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php) class*

1. Type the word “get” without the quotation marks in the
   Filter Symbols’s search bar.
2. You can then click on any of the “get*” prefixed methods
   that show up in the list.

   - [`getGet(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/6c06f84663caf45d27d2883b476c3afc6c894b25/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php#L732)
   - [`getVar(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/6c06f84663caf45d27d2883b476c3afc6c894b25/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php#L545)
   - [`getFile(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/6c06f84663caf45d27d2883b476c3afc6c894b25/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php#L909)
   - [`getJSON(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/6c06f84663caf45d27d2883b476c3afc6c894b25/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php#L572)
   - [`getPath(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/6c06f84663caf45d27d2883b476c3afc6c894b25/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php#L481)
   - [`getPost(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/6c06f84663caf45d27d2883b476c3afc6c894b25/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php#L746)
   - [`getFiles(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/6c06f84663caf45d27d2883b476c3afc6c894b25/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php#L879)
   - [`getCookie(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/6c06f84663caf45d27d2883b476c3afc6c894b25/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php#L806)
   - [`getLocale(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/6c06f84663caf45d27d2883b476c3afc6c894b25/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php#L521)
   - [`getGetPost(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/6c06f84663caf45d27d2883b476c3afc6c894b25/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php#L783)
   - [`getJsonVar(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/6c06f84663caf45d27d2883b476c3afc6c894b25/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php#L587)
   - [`getPostGet(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/6c06f84663caf45d27d2883b476c3afc6c894b25/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php#L760)
   - [`getOldInput(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/6c06f84663caf45d27d2883b476c3afc6c894b25/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php#L828)
   - [`getRawInput(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/6c06f84663caf45d27d2883b476c3afc6c894b25/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php#L662)
   - [`getUserAgent(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/6c06f84663caf45d27d2883b476c3afc6c894b25/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php#L816)
   - [`getPostMaxSize(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/6c06f84663caf45d27d2883b476c3afc6c894b25/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php#L189)
   - [`getRawInputVar(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/6c06f84663caf45d27d2883b476c3afc6c894b25/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php#L678)
   - [`getFileMultiple(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/6c06f84663caf45d27d2883b476c3afc6c894b25/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php#L894)
   - [`getDefaultLocale(...)`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/6c06f84663caf45d27d2883b476c3afc6c894b25/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php#L529)

[image]

3. Use the keyboard shortcut `r` to display the Filter Symbols’s search bar to allow you to search again. Alternatively, click the back button in the Symbols section to display the Filter Symbols’s search bar again.

[image]

*NOTE:* In addition to the methods listed here, this [IncomingRequest](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/system/HTTP/IncomingRequest.php) class inherits the methods from the [Request](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/system/HTTP/Request.php) Class and the [Message](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/system/HTTP/Message.php) Class.

##### Solution 2: Using CodeIgniter4's API documentation webpage

[CodeIgniter4's API documentation webpage](https://codeigniter4.github.io/api/classes/CodeIgniter-HTTP-IncomingRequest.html)

[image]